# setTranslationY messes up translate animations on a view that slides above another view?

Tags: android, animation

I initialize a ViewGroup with the code below. When a button is pressed I run        this.startAnimation(moveMenu). startAnimation will run the view's invalidate so it will draw something on the view. However, if I run setTranslationY in the function below then the view does not have the drawing show up properly. If I remove it then it works and slides down and then back up.

This is not the behavior I want though, I want the viewGroup to be hidden above the screen and slide down when the button is pressed, then slide back up to hide again. So this is why I need the       this.setTranslationY.

```
void init(Context context) {        
    this.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    this.setTranslationY(this.height * -1); // if I remove this the drawing works


    Resources r = this.getContext().getResources();
    loadBitmapArray(0, r.getDrawable(R.drawable.the_drawable)) ;    


    show = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, height);
    show.setDuration(1000);
    show.setFillAfter(true);

    hide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, -height);
    hide.setStartOffset(show.getDuration() + 2000);
    hide.setDuration(1000);
    hide.setFillAfter(true);

    moveMenu = new AnimationSet(true);
    moveMenu.addAnimation(show);
    moveMenu.addAnimation(hide);
}
```